# IBM Rational Synergy CLI get list of work area conflicts

Tags: cm-synergy

When using the Synergy GUI you can "sync work area" and then you get a list of files with conflicts.

I want to get the same list by using the CLI. However I have had no luck with this.

I've tried to use

```
ccm conflicts -r NAME:Version
```

And it prints the following

```
Checking for missing fix tasks., 11%...
Collecting objects and tasks beyond baseline., 32%...
Collecting objects and tasks beyond baseline., 46%...
Collecting objects and tasks beyond baseline., 48%...
Collecting objects and tasks beyond baseline., 49%...
Collecting objects and tasks beyond baseline., 50%...
Finding objects that are not included., 90%...
Conflict detection completed., 100%
Collecting objects and tasks beyond baseline., 20%...
Collecting objects and tasks beyond baseline., 26%...
Collecting objects and tasks beyond baseline., 32%...
Collecting objects and tasks beyond baseline., 38%...
Collecting objects and tasks beyond baseline., 44%...
Collecting objects and tasks beyond baseline., 49%...
Finding objects that are not included., 90%...
Conflict detection completed., 100%
Finding objects that are not included., 90%...
Conflict detection completed., 100%
Conflict detection completed., 100%
Getting explicitly included objects., 16%...
Finding objects that are not included., 90%...
Conflict detection completed., 100%
```

But I get no list of files.

If I do the same through the GUI. IE calls the Sync work area on members only. I get a list of about 30 files.

What am I doing wrong.

Do i need to run a Query instead. And where do I find information on what I can query after Keywoards ect.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try the command
`ccm reconcile -s -p NAME -cu`

This will do your "sync work area".

Further information about the command is documented in the synergy online help:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRNYG_7.2.1/com.ibm.rational.synergy.manage.doc/topics/sc_t_h_show_work_area_conflicts.html